# toggleCase: only getting back the first character of the input string

Tags: function, loops, unit-testing, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to write a program that, given a string, converts all uppercase characters to lowercase, and all lowercase characters to uppercase.

For my assertEqual test, I'm using the string 'Test'
The expected result is: tEST
but I'm getting back: t

Here's the error message from the assertEqual test:

FAILED [should change upper case to lower case and lower case to upper case Expected tEST but got: t

I was using an alias for for the current element in the loop, I tried removing that, but nothing changed.

```
// inputs: a string 
// outputs: a new string with all the input string cases switched(ex: UPPER -> upper)
// create an empty string to add characters to
var cased = '';
// split the input string up into an array or characters
function splitUp(string) {
  var stringArray = string.split('');
// iterate over the array of characters
for(var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
  // if stringArray[i] is equal to the upper-case version of itself,
  if(stringArray[i] === stringArray[i].toUpperCase()) {
    // change it to lower case
    stringArray[i] = stringArray[i].toLowerCase();
      // add lower-cased character to cased string
      cased += stringArray[i];
  // otherwise, if character is equal to the lower-case version of itself
  } else if(stringArray[i] === stringArray[i].toLowerCase) {
    // change it to upper case
    stringArray[i] = stringArray[i].toUpperCase();
      // add upper-cased character to cased string
      cased += stringArray[i];
    }
  }
return cased;
}

// ASSERTION FUNCTIONS
function assertEqual(actual, expected, testName) {
if(actual === expected){
  console.log('passed')
} else {
  console.log(`FAILED [${testName} Expected ${expected} but got ${actual}`)
  }
}

// TEST CASES
var actualCaseTest = splitUp('Test');
var expectedCaseTestResult = 'tEST';
assertEqual(actualCaseTest, expectedCaseTestResult, 'should change upper case to lower case and lower case to upper case');
```

Comment: Since `stringArray` does not contain any functions, `stringArray[i]` will never be equal to `stringArray[i].toLowerCase`, though it may be equal to `stringArray[i].toLowerCase()`. Closing as typo. (Also note that `var cased = ""` needs to be inside the function, or the function will only work correctly once.)

Comment: So I'm going about solving the problem the wrong way?

Comment: I wouldn't call one typo and one placement error "wrong way". Move the variable declaration, add the needed parentheses, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! I will move the var cased = "" and see if it helps.

Comment: I forgot to add a set of parentheses!! Thank you so much! Thank you for pointing that out. Everything's working fine now.